# Voltage drops when current reaches limit on supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current

Why is it, when I'm powering a circuit via a lab bench power supply set to limit 2 mA and the current drawn from the circuit reaches the limit, the supply voltage drops?

Comment: What else would you expect?

Comment: Ohm's law is the likely answer.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if the supply **did not** drop the voltage. Suppose your load wants to draw 100 mA at the voltage you have set. If that voltage was maintained, then 100 mA would flow, right? That then violates the 2 mA maximum you also set. So the supply has to drop the voltage such that only 2 mA flows and no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called Constant Current Constant Voltage (CC/CV). The power supply has to lower the voltage to keep the current at the limit, when the current limit is reached. If the voltage were to keep rising then the current limit you set would be violated.

Imagine if you had a simple resistive load. If the voltage goes up so does the current. So in order for the power supply to maintain the max allowed current, it must keep the voltage fixed at a lower setting.

Answer (score 0):

First, any two-terminal device can control its current *or* its voltage *or* some combination of the two.  You can't control both independently without controlling the two-terminal device to which it's connected.

Second, most lab supplies are constant-voltage/constant current supplies.  They're designed to deliver a set voltage unless doing so would exceed a set current, in which case they hold that set current instead.  If you were to plot their current-voltage characteristic, it would be the upper right corner of a square.

Assuming that you have a CV/CC supply, then if, at your set voltage, the circuit "wants" to draw more than 2mA, the lab supply will drop the voltage until the circuit only draws 2mA, because that's what it's designed to do.